# SQL error - Failed to add the foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_id INT,
    first_name VARCHAR(40),
    last_name VARCHAR(40),
    birth_day DATE,
    sex VARCHAR(1),
    salary INT,
    super_id INT,
    branch_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_id)
);

CREATE TABLE branch(
    branch_id INT,
    branch_name VARCHAR(40),
    mgr_id INT,
    mgr_start_date DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY(mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);



ALTER TABLE employee
ADD FOREIGN KEY(branch_id)
REFERENCES branch(branch_id)
ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I run the lasts query, I keep getting the

> "failed to add the foreign key constraint"

error saying there's a missing index for constraint 'employee_ibfk_2' in the reference table 'branch'

Answer (score 1):

Columns referenced in a foreign key must be a key.

Presumably you forgot to declare `branch_id` as primary key?

Try:

```
...

CREATE TABLE branch(
    branch_id INT,
    branch_name VARCHAR(40),
    mgr_id INT,
    mgr_start_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (branch_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);

...
```

Comment: thank you so much!! I completely forgot about setting it as primary key!

Answer (score 0):

The `branch_id` column in your `branch` table is not indexed. a requirement for foreign key constraints.

Add an index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `branch` 
ADD INDEX `branch_id` (`branch_id` ASC) VISIBLE;
;
```